# Unable to execute data.sql and schema.sql at Spring Boot Startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to execute some DB initialization for a Spring Boot application against a MySQL Database that is running in a container.
During the authentication process, I receive an error "Table  not found". I've checked the DB and no tables have been created indeed.
Is there something missing in DB properties?

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/schema
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.data.rest.basePath=/
spring.datasource.data = classpath:/data.sql
spring.datasource.schema = classpath:/schema.sql
```

All in all, the JDBC Settings work fine provided that I create the DDL from the mysql command line. So it's just not executing the data.sql and schema.sql at startup.
Do I need some extra properties for mysql ?

Comment: Have you defined your **spring.datasource.driverclassname**?

Comment: Are you using `spring-data`?

Comment: I have just tried adding the driverclasname but it didn't change. Also I'm using 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'. Does it make difference?

Comment: Are you certain that you provided the correct path to your sql files? Maybe you can try adding your sql files into the resources folder and remove the `spring.datasource.data = classpath:/data.sql 
spring.datasource.schema = classpath:/schema.sql`

Comment: @Carla - Were you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

You can update the application.properties with following properties.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

By default value of **spring.jpa.generate-ddl** is false. If you set **spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true** or **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** to any of value **validate**, **update**, **create**, **create-drop**. Spring boot generates schema scripts and creates the tables based on the entities available in your application.

Now you should create the **schema.sql** and **data.sql** files under resources folder and set the property **spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always** in application.properties.

You can also run the scripts based on the platform. Let's suppose you want to run the scripts for **hsqldb** database, then set **spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb** in application.properties file and created scripts file **schema-hsqldb.sql** and **data-hsqldb.sql** under resources folder.
You can find more details about [how to load schema.sql and data.sql on startup with spring boot](https://walkingtechie.blogspot.com/2018/12/execute-schema-and-data-sql-on-startup-spring-boot.html).

Comment: Does this process works for any DB ? I dont see its working with these configurations. Any pointers here ?

Comment: fyi, spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always seems now to have been replaced by spring.sql.init.mode=always (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as expected until a spring-boot update the pom file from

```
<version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
```

to

```
<version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
```

A switch back and update all test are passed without any exceptions. In Version 2.3.3  a test fault caused by missing data in database.
I've spend hours to solve the ddl initialization for Spring Version 2.3.3.RELEASE without find regular solution.

Answer (score 1):

For spring boot version 2.7, ensure that you have configured `spring.sql.init.mode` property in the application.properties file

Example:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Spring doesn't run the schema.sql and data.sql.

Try it with

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried changing to 'none' but it still doesn't execute the SQL files.